# Energy Transformations in a Motor

Tags: energy, electric-circuits, electromagnetic-induction

I'm confused about how the energy transformations in a motor work. I'm not comprehending how the electrical potential energy within the circuit is transformed to rotational kinetic energy of the coil, and how the Law of Conservation of Energy is obeyed. I've read that the energy stored in a magnetic field is equal to the work done in setting up the current which produces it.However, I read that magnetic fields cannot do work. So it must be some other source converting the electrical potential energy of the circuit to rotational kinetic energy.

So ultimately my question is: how exactly is the electrical potential energy ultimately converted to kinetic energy? How does this relate to the energy of the magnetic and electric fields of the current-carrying coil?

Comment: Duplicate? [DC motors, back emf, mechanical power output of a DC motor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/276645/)

Answer (score 0):

A uniform, stationary, continuous magnetic field can do no work itself. A fluxing magnetic field can convey the energy it takes to create the flux. In an electric motor electromagnets are turned on and off or alternated in order to create a fluxing magnetic field. The electrical energy required to create the changing magnetic field is the actual source of the energy that is converted to kinetic energy.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. In that case, does that mean the electric current will lose energy by the law of conservation of energy? How will this affect the current itself, since current and electrical energy are not the same thing?

Comment: The coil of the electromagnet uses electrical energy as it creates the magnetic field and some waste heat. Conservation of energy law is maintained. I made a minor edit to the answer that may make it easier to understand. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped :)