# An electric motor operates on a 50 V supply and a current of 12 A. If the efficiency of the motor is 30% what is the resistance of winding of motor?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, power

This is not a textbook question,i want to understand why it would generate two different values? and I cannot do that without invoking some form of numerical value in my question

Ok so I get that the power dissipated as heat is$$P=0.7*50*12=420$$
So but to calculate the resistance if I use the formula $$R=\frac{P}{I^2}$$
I get $R=2.9$
However if i use $$R=\frac{V^2}{P}$$
I get $R=5.95$
Why is there a difference,i assume that it might be because the potential difference across the resistor is different than 50V(because of conservation of current,$I$ must be the same),but why would  a non efficient machine behave as such?

Comment: Related [In the case of DC motors why is the mechanical power output  equal to back emf multiplied by armature current.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/276645/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DC motors, back emf, mechanical power output of a DC motor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/276645/dc-motors-back-emf-mechanical-power-output-of-a-dc-motor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Energy losses due to current flowing in an element of wire are given by the formula

$$
RI^2
$$
where $R$ is resistance of the wire element and $I$ is current there.

The formula
$$
\frac{V^2}{R}
$$

is not applicable in an electric motor because of presence of "back-emf" (motional electromotive force due to motion of the winding in magnetic field) acting on the current, and this effect is not described by the applied voltage $V$.

The latter formula is applicable only when the only force pushing the current against the resistance is voltage (conservative electric field), like in a resistor in ordinary circuit (not moving in magnetic field).

Comment: Thanks,you see my stupid text book asked the question and didn't yet explain about back emf

Comment: Well, the question is answerable even without the knowledge of back-emf, provided you know about the Joule heating $RI^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Your second equation is based on $V=IR$ where $V$ is the supply voltage. But the supply voltage is the total voltage across the motor, which, in the case of induction motors, is modeled as a combination of resistance and inductance. It is not the voltage across the resistive components of the motor only, which would be less than the supply voltage.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I wish I could accept both answers but i haven't read about inductance and his back emf made much more sense

Comment: @Karan Self inductance and back emf describe the same phenomenon.  A back emf is $\mathcal{E}=-L\dot{I}$, where $L$ is the self inductance.