# Relation between input electrical power and output mechanical power of DC motor

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, power, home-experiment

I am trying to understand how to calculate the mechanical power output of a DC motor. My thinking is as follows.

I believe that the power input should equal to the mechanical power output plus some lost power:
$$P_{\text{electrical}}=P_{\text{mechanical output}}+P_{\text{lost}}$$

Now, I have seen (in my book) that a back emf $\epsilon$ is created in the motor, and hence the voltage on the motor's winding is, for the steady state:
$$V=\epsilon+IR$$
where $I$ is the current in the winding and $R$ is its resistance. Using the formula for electrical power,
$$P_{\text{electrical}}=IV=I\epsilon +I^2R$$

I think that the $I^2R$ is the lost power, because the resistance is what causes friction losses (I hope I am making sense). So overall, this implies that:
$$P_{\text{electrical}}=I\epsilon+I^2R \\ P_{\text{lost}}=I^2R \\ P_{\text{mechanical output}}=I\epsilon \stackrel{?}{=}I(V-IR)$$

Is this correct?

My goal is to experimentally calculate the mechanical power of a DC motor, by applying a certain voltage to it ($4 \,\text{V}$), and calculating its steady-state rotational velocity and current.

Any help is appreciated, and I am sorry if my understanding is worse than I think.

Comment: Duplicate [DC motors, back emf, mechanical power output of a DC motor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/276645/)

Answer (score 0):

That's one of the losses. Others include hysteresis and eddy currents in the magnetics, as well as mechanical friction, of course.

Comment: So how can one experimentally measure the power of a DC motor?

Comment: @HappyDay The instrument is called a dynamometer, and there are many approaches to constructing one. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamometer